# django, creating qrcode.png file for a new instance in signals.py

Tags: django, amazon-s3, qr-code, django-signals

I will like to create a qrcode.png file and store it in my S3 bucket once a instance gets created in models.Model (using signals.py). With my code below I managed to create the qrcode__png file in my local base directory but it does not upload to my external S3 bucket or save in my models.Model class. HELP! Thanks.
Signals.py

@receiver(post_save,sender=inventory)

def create__url_qr(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

```
if created == True:
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            box_size=10,
            border=5)
    qr.add_data('/MyProperty/item/'+str(instance.id))
    qr.make(fit=True)
    im=qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    im.save('qrcode___'+str(instance.id)+'.png', format="png")
    print('XXXX')
    print(im)
    print('XXXX')
    inst1 = inventory.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)        
    inst1.qr_code = im
    inst1.save()
```

Comment: hi have you read the https://github.com/dprog-philippe-docourt/django-qr-code. with this you can create a qr code with without having to store the image inside your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file you wrote into a `django.core.files.File` object and then save that object to your model

```
import qrcode
from django.core.files import File
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    box_size=10,
    border=5,
)
qr.add_data('/MyProperty/item/'+str(instance.id))
qr.make(fit=True)
im = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
im.save('qrcode___'+str(instance.id)+'.png', format="png")
qr_file = File(open('qrcode___'+str(instance.id)+'.png'))
inst1 = inventory.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
inst1.qr_code.save('qrcode___'+str(instance.id)+'.png', qr_file)
```

But you don't have to save it locally first, you could just write it to BytesIO and then save it

```
import qrcode
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    box_size=10,
    border=5,
)
qr.add_data('/MyProperty/item/'+str(instance.id))
qr.make(fit=True)
im = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
stream = BytesIO()
im.save(stream, format="png")
qr_file = File(stream)
inst1 = inventory.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
inst1.qr_code.save('qrcode___'+str(instance.id)+'.png', qr_file)
```